# Postgres Grant SELECT & UPDATE privilege ONLY to a user

Tags: database, postgresql, database-schema, privileges

Can anyone kindly tell me how I can grant a user (username: restricted_user) with only SELECT AND UPDATE privilege on postgresql? I'm running centos.

At the moment the user cannot select anything. I've logged in to phpPgMyAdmin and i can only seem to grant the SELECT and UPDATE privilege per table for the user which works but I would like to apply this rule for all tables across all databases.

thanks

Comment: You could start by reading the documentation... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can grant to all tables in a schema at once:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO restricted_user;
```

If there are [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) columns or other SEQUENCES in use, you need also:

```
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO restricted_user;
```

Run for every relevant schema. [More in the fine manual for `GRANT`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html)
You also need is the `USAGE` privilege on each schema:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO restricted_user;
```

If you have another user creating more objects, you probably want to grant the same privileges for future objects by default, too. That's where [**`DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) come in:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR creating_user IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON TABLES TO restricted_user;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR creating_user IN SCHEMA public
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO restricted_user;
```